Recursive one-step forecasting in timeseries model
I am trying to implement a recursive one-step forecasting approach for a Random Forest model.
The idea is to get a 12-months forecast in an iterative way where each prediction becomes part of the history before the next prediction.
Given that I do not retrain the model and that the error of the model compounds on each recursive prediction step, I would expect the plot of error to be increasing steadily. However, there is no such trend.
I am wondering if there is any issue in the implementation. I want to test the predictive power of the model in a real-world scenario where we iteratively predict next values (e.g. if I want to have a 12 months forecast).
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(1)

# Create date range
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2024-12-31', freq='MS')
n_points = len(date_rng)

# Trend component (linear growth)
trend = np.linspace(100, 200, n_points)
seasonal = 20 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(n_points) / 12)
cyclical = 30 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(n_points) / (12 * 3))
noise = np.random.normal(0, 10, n_points)
values = trend + seasonal + cyclical + noise

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': date_rng,
    'value': values
})

# Format the data
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['value'] = df['value'].round(2)


# build temporal features
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['quarter'] = df.index.quarter
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['sin_month'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * df.index.month / 12)
df['cos_month'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * df.index.month / 12)

# Build lags
num_lags = 12
lagged_columns = {f'lag_{lag}': df['value'].shift(lag) for lag in range(1, num_lags + 1)}
df = df.assign(**lagged_columns)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Simple Moving Average (SMA)
sma_window_size = 12
df[f'SMA_{sma_window_size}'] = df['value'].rolling(window=sma_window_size).mean()

# Exponential Moving Average (EMA)
ema_span_size = 9
df[f'EMA_{ema_span_size}'] = df['value'].ewm(span=ema_span_size).mean()


# split data and fit model
split_point = '2023-12-31'

# Split into train and test
train = df.query('date <= @split_point')
test = df.query('date > @split_point')

# Create train features and target
X_train = train.drop(columns=['value', 'date'])
y_train = train['value']

# Create test features and target
X_test = test.drop(columns=['value', 'date'])
y_test = test['value']

rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, 
                               max_depth=10,
                               random_state=0)
rf_model.fit(X_train, y_train)


# Number of forecast steps
num_forecasts = 12 
all_forecasts = {}

# get last train sample
X_last = train.iloc[[-1]].drop(columns=[col for col in train.columns.tolist() if col not in X_train.columns.tolist()])  # Drop identifiers that do not exist in X_train


forecasts = []

for step in range(num_forecasts):

    # Make prediction
    y_pred = rf_model.predict(X_last.values.reshape(1, -1))[0]
    forecasts.append(y_pred)

    # Update lags
    X_last_series = pd.Series(X_last.iloc[0])
    lags = X_last_series.filter(like='lag_').copy().shift(1, axis=0)
    lags['lag_1'] = y_pred
    X_last_series.update(lags)


    # Update seasonal or static features if necessary
    if 'month' in X_last_series.index and 'quarter' in X_last_series.index:
        # Month and Quarter
        current_month = X_last_series['month'] % 12 + 1

        X_last_series['month'] = current_month
        X_last_series['quarter'] = (current_month - 1) // 3 + 1
        
        # Year (increment if month wraps around to January)
        if current_month == 1:
            X_last_series['year'] += 1
            
        # Sinusoidal transformations for cyclical features (month)
        X_last_series['sin_month'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * current_month / 12)
        X_last_series['cos_month'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * current_month / 12)
    
    # Update rolling features
    if f'SMA_{sma_window_size}' in X_last_series.index:
        past_values = X_last_series.filter(like='lag_').values[:sma_window_size - 1]
        X_last_series[f'SMA_{sma_window_size}'] = np.mean(np.append(past_values, y_pred))

    if f'EMA_{ema_span_size}' in X_last_series.index:
        ema_alpha = 2 / (ema_span_size + 1)
        X_last_series[f'EMA_{ema_span_size}'] = ema_alpha * y_pred + (1 - ema_alpha) * X_last_series[f'EMA_{ema_span_size}']


    # Update X_last for the next forecast step
    X_last = X_last_series.to_frame().T

all_forecasts['results'] = {
'forecasts': forecasts,
'actuals': y_test
}


def calculate_mape(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

steps_mape = []
for i in range(num_forecasts):  
    steps_mape.append(calculate_mape(y_test[i], forecasts[i]))

plt.plot(steps_mape)


EDIT: I though to look at the error from another point of view. Instead of calculating MAPE at each step, I now estimate cumulative MAPE over steps (e.g., MAPE at step 3 is the MAPE of the first three forecasts)
Like a running average up to each step.
Now things look more like expected however, I am wondering whether this approach is sound.
all_cumulative_mapes = []

# Loop over time series
for series_id, forecast_data in all_forecasts.items():
    actuals = forecast_data['actuals']
    forecasts = forecast_data['forecasts']

    cumulative_mape = []
    cumulative_error_sum = 0

    # Calculate cumulative MAPE over forecast steps
    for i in range(num_forecasts):
        # Calculate APE for current step
        ape = np.abs((actuals[i] - forecasts[i]) / actuals[i]) * 100
        
        # Update cumulative error sum and cumulative MAPE
        cumulative_error_sum += ape
        cumulative_mape_value = cumulative_error_sum / (i + 1)
        cumulative_mape.append(cumulative_mape_value)
    
    all_cumulative_mapes.append(cumulative_mape)

all_cumulative_mapes = np.array(all_cumulative_mapes)

plt.plot(np.mean(all_cumulative_mapes, axis=0), '-o', label="Average Cumulative MAPE")
plt.title(f"Average (across timeseries) Cumulative MAPE% over Forecast Steps")
plt.xlabel("Forecast Step")
plt.ylabel("Cumulative MAPE (%)")


